# In data snapshot i couldn't get the values outside from it

Tags: android, firebase

I've tried several times to get the values of the strings `month`, `firstWeek`, `secondWeek`, and `thirdWeek` from the `DataSnapshot` class but I couldn't take the values from the `DataSnapshot` class to the line `monthSalesDataArrayList.add(new MonthSalesData("1st Week", firstWeek));` (It doesn't work). After that I tried to set the text on the `TextView` using `FirstWeek.setText(firstWeek);` it takes the value and displays on the screen but not taking the value on the array. After that I tried with the Toast message whether it shows the value or not but the value doesn't shows on the toast message it's empty there, please help me out to take the `DataSnapshot` values  to `monthSalesDataArrayList.add(new MonthSalesData("1st Week", **"to Here"**));`

```
public void takeMonthSales(){
    GetRecord = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Graph").child("Record");
    GetRecord.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String month = dataSnapshot.child("Month").getValue(String.class);
                String firstWeek = dataSnapshot.child("1st week").getValue().toString();
                String secondWeek = dataSnapshot.child("2nd week").getValue().toString();
                String thirdWeek = dataSnapshot.child("3rd week").getValue().toString();
                String fourthWeek = dataSnapshot.child("4th week").getValue().toString();
                setMonth.setText("Month of report " + month);
                FirstWeek.setText(firstWeek);
                SecondWeek.setText(secondWeek);
                ThirdWeek.setText(thirdWeek);
                FourthWeek.setText(fourthWeek);

    

        }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    
                }
            });
    
            Toast.makeText(AdminGraphView.this, "The value is " + FirstWeek.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
    //This is the array for the barchart values to the graph
        
    
        monthSalesDataArrayList.clear();
        monthSalesDataArrayList.add(new MonthSalesData("1st Week", "58454"));
        monthSalesDataArrayList.add(new MonthSalesData("2nd Week", "72636"));
        monthSalesDataArrayList.add(new MonthSalesData("3rd Week", "62301"));
        monthSalesDataArrayList.add(new MonthSalesData("4th Week", "85656"));
        // enter code here
    
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By cleaning up the indentation of your code the problem becomes clearly visible - the variables `firstWeek`, `secondWeek` and so on are not in the same scope as the `Toast` and `monthSalesDataArrayList` instructions. This code is also asyncronous - the code inside of the `onDataChange` event handler is not executed before you try to use the text inside of the `TextView` `FirstWeek`.

```
public void takeMonthSales(){
    GetRecord = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Graph").child("Record");
    GetRecord.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String month = dataSnapshot.child("Month").getValue(String.class);
            String firstWeek = dataSnapshot.child("1st week").getValue().toString();
            String secondWeek = dataSnapshot.child("2nd week").getValue().toString();
            String thirdWeek = dataSnapshot.child("3rd week").getValue().toString();
            String fourthWeek = dataSnapshot.child("4th week").getValue().toString();
            setMonth.setText("Month of report " + month);
            FirstWeek.setText(firstWeek);
            SecondWeek.setText(secondWeek);
            ThirdWeek.setText(thirdWeek);
            FourthWeek.setText(fourthWeek);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
    
   Toast.makeText(AdminGraphView.this, "The value is " + FirstWeek.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
    //This is the array for the barchart values to the graph
   monthSalesDataArrayList.clear();
   monthSalesDataArrayList.add(new MonthSalesData("1st Week", "58454"));
   monthSalesDataArrayList.add(new MonthSalesData("2nd Week", "72636"));
   monthSalesDataArrayList.add(new MonthSalesData("3rd Week", "62301"));
   monthSalesDataArrayList.add(new MonthSalesData("4th Week", "85656"));
   // enter code here
}
```

You need to move these instructions inside of the `addValueEventListener` event handlers.

```
public void takeMonthSales(){
    // use a local variable here! (if you are using it elsewhere, you should initialize it elsewhere not here)
    DatabaseReference recordRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Graph").child("Record"); 
    recordRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String month = dataSnapshot.child("Month").getValue(String.class);
            String firstWeek = dataSnapshot.child("1st week").getValue().toString();
            String secondWeek = dataSnapshot.child("2nd week").getValue().toString();
            String thirdWeek = dataSnapshot.child("3rd week").getValue().toString();
            String fourthWeek = dataSnapshot.child("4th week").getValue().toString();
            setMonth.setText("Month of report " + month);
            FirstWeek.setText(firstWeek);
            SecondWeek.setText(secondWeek);
            ThirdWeek.setText(thirdWeek);
            FourthWeek.setText(fourthWeek);

            Toast.makeText(AdminGraphView.this, "The value is " + FirstWeek.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
            //This is the array for the barchart values to the graph
            monthSalesDataArrayList.clear();
            monthSalesDataArrayList.add(new MonthSalesData("1st Week", firstWeek));                              
            monthSalesDataArrayList.add(new MonthSalesData("2nd Week", secondWeek));
            monthSalesDataArrayList.add(new MonthSalesData("3rd Week", thirdWeek));
            monthSalesDataArrayList.add(new MonthSalesData("4th Week", fouthWeek));
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // TODO: Implement error handling!
       }
   });
}
```

Also, the `onDataChange` may be rerun if the data at `/Graph/Record` is edited. If you want this code to run just once, use [`addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) instead.